# Node.js is installed but it's not usable

Tags: node.js, linux, installation, debian

I'm using Debian 9.1.0 and I have installed Node.js by downloading the LTS version `Linux Binaries (x64)`.

From the location (where I installed Node.js), I can use it:

```
$ cd /home/<user>Softwares/nodejs/
$ ./node -v
# displays: v6.11.3
```

But when I run it outside this location, like:

```
$ cd ~/
$ node -v
```

I got the error:

> bash: node: command not found

The solution I found on Internet: create a symlink

```
sudo ln -s ~/Softwares/nodejs/ /usr/local/bin/nodejs
```

doesn't help me.

Comment: Assuming you're on a basically single-user system, why don't you just update the `PATH` in your `.bashrc` or do an `alias node="~/Softwares/nodejs/node"`? Your `ln` would require you to do `nodejs/node` to run it, I think.

Comment: I already did `export PATH=$PATH:/home/<me>/Softwares/nodejs/bin` so it works until I reboot my PC. It seems like this command doesn't persist

Comment: Yes, you need to edit `~/.bashrc` to get `PATH` and `alias` settings to persist.

Comment: thanks but how to add it to `~/.bashrc` I tried with `echo 'export PATH=$PATH:/home/<me>/Softwares/nodejs/bin:$PATH' >> ~/.bashrc` but it doesn't help!

Comment: I think it would be better to post this as a question to [linux.se] rather than continuing discussing things in the comments here - your post indicates that the `node` executable is not in `bin`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm sharing the solution I found based on the comment of [Ken Y-N](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1270789/ken-y-n).

I'm missing 2 steps:

Update the `PATH` in my `.bashrc` using:

```
$ echo 'export PATH=$PATH:/home/<username>/Softwares/nodejs/bin:$PATH' >> ~/.bashrc
```

Run [make install](https://superuser.com/questions/360178/what-does-make-install-do)

```
$ cd ~/

$ make install
```